# Setting up Facebook SASL authentication in XMPPFramework

Tags: iphone, facebook, xmpp

Any clue on how to setup the facebook SASL authentication in XMPPFramework for iPhone.

I dont need to get the accesstoken. I have the accesstoken already. So I can use it.

Update: I started implementing [this documented way](http://groups.google.com/group/xmppframework/browse_thread/thread/542004122269250d/aa3c25120636bb0d?lnk=gst&q=facebook#aa3c25120636bb0d) But got stuck up with this stack overflow [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701460/facebook-chat-difficulty-users-jid)

Answer (score 1):

XMPPFramework was recently updated to work with the Facebook OAuth2 changes.  Instructions explaining how to configure the integration are in the project wiki and there is now a sample Facebook test application.